# read equivalent for filebuf?

Tags: c++, iostream

```
typedef struct {
  char c[20];
  int i;
} header;

void foo(std::string s) {
  std::ifstream ifs(s.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);
  if (ifs) {
    std::filebuf* pbuf = ifs.rdbuf();
    pbuf->pubseekpos(std::ios_base::beg); 
    // ... ?
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read a file in binary mode the C++ way, I can't identify the right method to call for reading the bits from the file, there is a `read` for `ifstream` but if I'm supposed to use that method, what is the point of `filebuf` ?

To simplify things I have a `struct` that represents the order, the size and the fields of the header and I hope that there will be a method that would just keep and instance of this struct and write the bits in right fields just like `fread` from C.

Someone can clarify the point of `filebuf` and what method should I use when reading a file through an unformatted stream of data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`basic_istream<>::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read raw, unformatted byte data:

```
void foo(std::string s) {
  std::ifstream ifs(s.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);
  if (ifs) {
    char buffer[20];
    if (!ifs.read(buffer, 20)) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, but my first approach is wrong ? it's good or bad ? `read` is the only method for this ?

Comment: I can't say, I'm not very familiar with `filebuf` objects, but `read()` is definitely the preferred method of reading unformatted data.  It's entirely the equivalent of C's `fread()`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield It's not really the equivalent of `fread`; it's error handling is significantly different.  As for being preferred, it largely depends on context; there are cases where using the `streambuf` may be preferrable, and others where `istream::read` is preferrable.

Answer (score 2):

First, the real point of `filebuf` is that it derives from
`streambuf`, and that an `istream` whose streambuf is a filebuf
will behave largely like an `ifstream`.  This is important; the
`>>` operator aren't virtual, and since many of them aren't
members, they cannot be virtual.  All input must pass through
the `istream`, not the `ifstream` that's derived from it.  More
generally, the `ifstream` can be thought of as just 
a convenience class; it's constructor provides the `istream`
base class with a `filebuf`, its destructor destructs the
`filebuf`, and it provides access to the functionality of
`filebuf` which isn't present in the base `streambuf`.

That doesn't mean that you cannot use the `streambuf` directly,
you can, and there are cases where it is appropriate.  But if
you do, *you* have to take care of the error handling.  When you
call `istream::read` asking for a certain number of bytes, and
those bytes aren't there, `istream::read` will note the end of
file, set the necessary error bits, and provide the count of
what was actually read through `istream::gcount`.  If you're
reading byte by byte, and don't know how many bytes there might
be, then all of that may not mean much (but you'll probably want
to set `eofbit` if you see EOF).  If you're trying to read
a specific number of bytes (say a four byte integer), then
`istream:read` will set the appropriate error bits if you cannot
read four bytes, so you can easily test for the error.

EDIT

One additional comment: you should probably put the reading of
the file in a separate process, which takes an `std::istream&`.
You really don't want the reading code to know that it is
dealing with an `ifstream`, rather than some other sort of
stream.  (Also: there's no need to seek if you've just opened
the file.)

Comment: do you mean opening the file with an instance of `std::ifstream` like `ifs` in this case and than pass a reference to `ifs` to a function with the following signature `void bar( std::istream& ist )` ?

Comment: also one final question, I should pass a real pointer to a `char[]` that is the size of the header or force a cast to `char*` when using `read` with a pointer to `header` ? Or maybe I can simply use `reinterpret_cast` ...

Comment: @user2485710 With regards to the first comment: exactly.  You'll want to separate the logic of handling the open and its errors from the logic of actually reading the file.  And who knows: you might later want to read the data from the network, using a custom `streambuf`, instead of `filebuf`.  As for the second: if your solution involves a `reinterpret_cast`, it's certainly wrong.  You need to read the data into a buffer of `char`, and then parse it, according to the format of the file you're reading.

Comment: so no easy way and no practical usage for my `struct` that defines the header ?

Comment: @user2485710 A `struct` can't define external data.  It only defines an internal representation.

Comment: are you saying that this defeats the concept of "type safety" ? how I should perform this ?

Comment: @user2485710 It has nothing to do with type safety.  The data in the external file have some well specified format, as a sequence of bytes.  There's not necessarily any relationship between that format and the layout your compiler uses in memory (which can even change from one version to the next).  So you need program against the specification of the external layout.  If, for example, the specification says that integers are 4 eight bit bytes, with the first byte the high order byte, then you have to construct an integer using 4 bytes, shifting the first 24 bits, the second 16 and so on.

Comment: ah, ok, so you are talking about platform specific implementation details about the size of the various types, I'm planning to use a typedef for the types used inside the struct and than change the type according to the platform if needed, I don't think that I'll experience problems because of the wrong size of my types.

Comment: @user2485710 Not just size.  Different machines have different ways of representing the different types.  And different requirements with regards to alignment.  You simply cannot dump the bytes of a `struct` to a file, and expect to be able to read it later.

Comment: I would like to know how I can do this the correct way. I think that I'll open a new question about this

Answer (score 1):

> there is a `read` for `ifstream`

Yes, and that's what you use to read unformatted data from the stream; hence the name.

> if I'm supposed to use that method, what is the point of `filebuf` ?

It's used by the stream to handle low-level file access and buffering. You can access it if you need to mess around with those details, but usually there's no need to. You certainly wouldn't mess around with it if you just want to read from the stream.

Comment: It's not rare to access it if you're implementing some very low level `operator>>`; at some point or another, some of the `operator>>` (and functions like `istream::read` have to access it.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the point of filebuf ?

None, here.

I can't see why you're using it.

Until you do more complex operations, `filebuf` is an implementation detail<sup>†</sup>.

<sup><sup>†</sup> (Sort of.)</sup>

Comment: I'm reading a file format that offers different implementations, different versions, so I need to check some bytes in the header, select the right "reader function" for the given implementation, re-seek the pointer to the beginning and proceed with reading the file. This file format also offers different sizes for the different headers in this different implementations, so I can't even re-use the header that I get the first time because it could be wrong.

Comment: @user2485710: None of this has anything to do with `filebuf`. The top-level member functions of your file stream provide you ample mechanism to read whatever bytes you want, and to seek around.

Comment: and how I'm supposed to reposition the pointer without filebuf ?

Comment: @user2485710: Why haven't you looked at the facilities provided by `fstream`, yet? _It gives you seek ability_. I don't know why you're obsessed with `filebuf` but stop it!